# How do I link two Access Tables so if one Table gets updated both will?

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, excel, ms-access-2016

I have an access database with a table that is linked to an excel sheet. I also have a duplicate table with the same data linked to a postgres database. My goal is to either link these two tables in such a way where when the excel linked table gets updated so does the postgres linked table or link a single table to both excel and postgre, is this even possible?

My ultimate goal is to use the excel sheet's data in a website. The excel sheet is the primary data source and all CRUD operations are done in excel, my website is simply a dashboard to display that data. I want my website to pull the data from the excel sheet when someone makes an edit and saves the file. As far as I know there's no way to do this without buying software. Since Access edits auto update a postgres database my thought process was to keep the existing links from excel to Access and then create another link from access to postgres and use postgres as the database my App would connect to.

Comment: Do you need the access database for something? You may consider using excel as a frontend to postgreSQL. You can have a look at: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Excel_Add-in_for_PostgreSQL. I see now that this is not for free, but it may give some ideas, so I'll leave my comment

Comment: @Lennart Thanks. I do need the access database as it's a central data storage for multiple people. They use excel and link his or her sheet to a single access table so the storage of data can be updated from anywhere and then imported into excel at anytime.